# Call method as user paste in textbox

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

```
<textarea name="" id="" #text cols="30" (keydown)="Counter()" (change)="Counter()" rows="8" [(ngModel)]="user_text" placeholder="Please write"></textarea>
```

I have this textarea i want to call counter method when the user types in the textarea

```
 wordCounter() {
    this.count= this.user_text.trim().split(/\s+/).length;
 }
```

this is working but when i paste anything in textarea then value not gets updated and value only gets updated when i click on window. I want count should get updated as soon user paste anything in textarea

Thanks

Comment: use the paste event

Comment: @pilchard Can i call same `Counter` method on paste event or i have to create another method for that?

Comment: @pilchard `(paste)="wordCounter()"` this is still not working

Answer (score 0):

Since your using Angular I would recommend using the formbuilder instead of NgModule and subscribe to the events there.

Checkout an example here:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-rwjwd5?file=src/app/app.component.ts

and Documentation here:
https://angular.io/api/forms/FormBuilder

Comment: Thanks will (ngModelChange) also work because i have not used formbuilder in my application so i have to change my application code